# validator gives 2 parse errors

Tags: css, validation, parse-error

W3 validator gives 2 parse errors when I try to validate .css by uploading file.
If I choose Checked by text input - everything is just fine.
Where is the problem?

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Nunito+Sans|Roboto&display=swap');
```

Comment: When I used the validator for the two lines above, it passed just fine. Please include the entire contents of the CSS file, and provide what the error messages say.

Comment: @Chris Forrence, the error comes only then you choose **File upload** -option  from **Checked by** -list. Put those 2 rows into .css file and you will see them.

Comment: I had done that, and it had passed successfully. Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing, you're uploading the CSS file to https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator (which is meant for validating CSS files specifically)?

Comment: I'm getting these errors on [https://validator.w3.org/nu/](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) and everything pass thru on website provided by you. Thank you!